# Maya Arnold RenderView : save rendered image as jpg with Python

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm trying to save already rendered image from the arnold renderview with Python or Mel
(like after an interactive session or simple render).
But so far I can't find how to do so, any help?

[save as renderview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLwW3.png)

Here's what I tried :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
editor = "renderView"
cmds.renderWindowEditor(editor, e=True, writeImage="C:/test.jpg")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong , you are just trying to save your rendered images right?

so in that case you can use the following to save the images at a specific location before rendering them itself (I have only used it while doing arnold render using script as well), you can give it a shot by setting this attribute manually and then taking renders.

```
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix", file_path, type="string")
```

where file_path will something like `destination + filename.extension`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it does set the filename but the image is not saved automatically at the end of the render.

Comment: @Tom what commands are you using to take arnold renders tho ? can you give me bit more insights,

as I have personally used renderseqence with some arnold settings and it worked fine

Comment: I'm using this command to render: 

`import maya.cmds as cmds;
from mtoa.cmds.arnoldRender import arnoldRender;
file_path = "C:/test";
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix", file_path, type="string");
cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.ai_translator", "jpeg", type="string");
arnoldRender(1920, 1080, True, True,"renderCam", ' -layer defaultRenderLayer');`

You mentionned rendersequence maybe I should see if this would work

Comment: @Tom for your reference you can use this 

            `mel.eval('renderSequenceOptionsWindow;')
            mel.eval('optionMenuGrp -e -v "{}" renderSequenceCameraList;'.format(facial_cam_node))
            mel.eval('renderSequenceCurrentCameraChanged();')
            mel.eval('renderSequence;')`

Comment: Thank you @Kartikey, it does work with render sequence and save the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar task. Try this bit of pure MEL code:

```
arnoldRenderView -opt "Save Image" "C:/testerImage.png"
```

I'm using this in Maya 2024 to save out rendered Arnold images. This little bit works great for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks promising but this makes maya crash on my end (2024).

Comment: I'm using 2024.1. I'll see if I can get mine to crash. I have a different directory for my actual use. I used the "C:/testerImage.png" path since that what you had in your original post. Maybe try a different path?